# Уязвимость на сайте

Tags: уязвимости

Нашел весомую уязвимость на крупном сайте. Хотел бы сообщить об этом администрации сайта. Вот только стоит ли это делать или нет? Может кто знает, как это сделать аккуратно...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Поискать баунти программу. Некоторые компании платят деньги если у них найти серьезную уязвимость. Поискать просто в гугле и на https://hackerone.com/ - это крупнейшая баунти площадка.
2. Сообщать неанонимно я бы строго не рекомендовал. Многие компании, особенно в России вместо того чтобы решать проблему начинают кидать предъявы и угрожать юристами. Особенно это характерно для "серьезного бизнеса" не связанного с айти. Поэтому всякие одноразовые аккаунты - нормальный путь.
3. Не пытайтесь ломиться через техподдержку, это практически бесполезно. Если имете дело с "серьезным бизнесом" вроде банков, то постарайтесь найти контакты службы безопасности, если что-нибудь серьезное найдется, то обычно получат втык непосредственно они (и это стоит им напомнить =)). Обычно легче выцепить в соцсетях людей непосредственно работающих с проектом, есть шанс найти человека которому не пофигу. У корпоратов есть одна особенность - их в общем в разы легче выцепить через email чем через другие способы связи.
4. Вас игнорируют? Остается три пути. Good: Написать статью на хабре, после которой компания обязательно зашевелится, neutral: забить на все и evil: слить уязвимость в даркнет.

Еще я придумал вариант "слить каким-нибудь внешним аудиторам, которые пользуясь знанием об уязвимости смогут продать себя компании", но на практике мне об осуществлении такой схемы неизвестно.

Comment: Компания ЮСА, мировой бренд.С IT связаны производством железа... 
Отписал, не отвечают 2-ой день. Говорят, что 24 часа.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе правильно сообщить администрации, с максимальным количеством деталей по самой уязвимости, желательно без собственных данных. У некоторых есть программы "найди баг, получишь бак ($$$)", если у этого сайта она есть, пость туда. Если сайт реально крупный (миллион или больше посетителей), а программы поиска багов нет, имеет смысл на хабре запостить, часто после такого пинка хозяева сайта шевелятся куда быстрее, чем даже после личного обращения.